# Downloading the google drive backups from the Backups folder

Tags: backup, download, google-drive, online-backup

In my google drive I have a folder called Backups. In the Backups folder I have 2 backups. How do I go about downloading these 2 files onto a local backup external drive so I can delete the backups from the google drive Backups folder to free up space?

The image below shows that there is no Download option when I right click one of the backup files I want to download.

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to do a backup of your backups before downloading your backups to your backup drive and deleting your backups... ;-)

(But seriously) I'm not sure you can download a phone backup to a PC.

Comment: There is no download option likely due to the size of the file.  The way you download files larger then the limit is to use the `Backup and Sync` client.  I am making an assumption the backups were NOT created by the phone itself.

Comment: @Ramhound, I'm fairly sure the backups were created by the phone itself.

Comment: Which means there isn't a file you can download.  Only Android can use those backups, similar to the iCloud backups, the iPhone uses.  If you want local backups of your phone use the appropriate software to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Those backups are meant for you to safely keep your contents backed up, it's not something that you simply download, the intention of such backups is that you can, in the event of loosing you locally stored data on your phone, that can be restored and potentially even to another new phone, you can find these settings under Settings:

[image]